# HDD SATA speed setting

Tags: hard-drive, ibm, sata, ibm-xseries

I just noticed this info from `smartctl`

Does that mean I'm running inferior SATA II speed?

If yes, how do I enable SATA III speed?

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WD1003FBYX-23        00W1143 00W1447IBM
Serial Number:    WD-WCAW3KXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20ad5d5f3
Firmware Version: WB35
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jun 15 05:02:43 2020 +08
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

```
IBM System x3100 M4 running Ubuntu server 20.04
```

Answer (score 0):

That old WDC hard drive [only supports SATA II](https://products.wdc.com/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701338.pdf). So while your old computer might support SATA III, depending on which storage controller card you have, it can only talk to the drive at 3Gbps. To get SATA III speeds, you will need to replace the drive with one that supports SATA III (and check the storage controller as well).

Comment: I have another old HDD that just says `SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s`, no mention of SATA 3.0 and another newer HDD says `SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)`